# c# store different settings in one object

Tags: c#, casting

I have an object that represents the current event that is taking place. This event contains a lot of settings. What is the best practice for storing all setting variables inside the event object?

The settings are stored in a database (right now in different columns based on the base class: ValueString, ValueInt, ValueBool, ValueDateTime, ValueFloat, ValueDecimal). A unique key represents the setting in the database.

As soon as i have loaded the events object i will store it in the local cache for quick access.

Should i cast everything to object? (Feels like un-needed casts to get/set settings)

```
class Event
{
    // string = settings key
    Dictionary<string, object> _settings;

    public void AddSetting(string key, object value)
    public object GetSetting(string key)
}
```

or should i have it in different dictionaries?

```
class Event
{
    // string = settings key
    Dictionary<string, string> _settingStrings;
    Dictionary<string, int> _settingInts;
    ...

    public void AddSetting(string key, string value)
    public void AddSetting(string key, int value)
    ...

    public string GetStringSetting(string key)
    public int GetIntSetting(string key)    
    ...
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do the settings not have semantic meaning? For instance, does one not relate to the `DateTime` the event takes place? I ask because `settingsInts` doesn't show it's intent, as a new developer to your code I have absolutely no idea at all what it relates to. If you can draw semantic meaning to each of these settings, it would probably work a lot better.

Comment: I would absolutely avoid storing everything as an object - you can get yourself into a whole lot of trouble real quick that way, as you'll have to know what to cast the object to (not to mention the conversion overhead).  I'm thinking generics might be a good answer here, though I'm not seeing a way to make it work outside of separate dictionaries for each type.

Comment: Example of settings would be: (string) search path to images, logo url, start page url (int) last inserted invoice id, number of items shown in a list (datetime) start date, end date, last signup date. These can vary between events so not all the keys are present in all events.

Comment: Are those all the settings?  That's not too many - I'd simply make one property for each setting in that case.  Though it's quite possible I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: That was just a few examples. An event can, right now, contain around 20-50 settings. But it will most likely increase in the future as new functionality is added and thus more settings are created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store everything as an `Object`, but rather than performing a straight cast, use generics to build an easy to use API:

```
private IDictionary<string,object> _settings = new Dictionary<string,object>();

public void AddSetting<T>(string key, T value) {
    _settings[key] = value;
}
public T GetSetting<T>(string key, T notFound = default(T)) {
    object res;
    if (!_settings.TryGetValue(key, out res) || !(res is T)) {
        return notFound;
    }
    return (T)res;
}
```

The cast remains there, but the API hides it from the user: now the user can safely write

```
string searchPath = settingContainer.GetSetting<string>("searchPath");
int retryCount = settingContainer.GetSetting<int>("retryCount", -1);
```

Comment: I figured generics would be a good way to deal with this, just hadn't muddle my way all the way through yet.

Comment: How does generics work when storing the data in an object? Os this not the same as just having a AddSetting(string key, object value) and then object GetSetting(string key) ? But instead of casting on the class side i cast it in here?

Comment: @Patrick Strings and other referenced types are already `object`s, so they go in as is. Primitives such as `int`, on the other hand, get wrapped before going into the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I really do like dasblinkenlight's answer.

Except instead of wasting one column for each datatype, I would rather have only **one column** (likely a VARCHAR) on your datatable.

Advantages of this:

- Faster reading (Only one indexed column)
- Saving up storage (Only one varchar per row)

And then you can either use generics as mentioned, or cast the string object in your implementation to your wished type.